# How to call jscript function with body onload in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I am new to this coding esp asp.net!! and im actually using jscript in asp.net.. so 
I want 6 div elements to appear once the page is loaded. I have done css for div class= div effect.. so 
here is my code and i am trying to call the $newfunc from the javascript code to the body section..

when I enter the body onload ="$newfunc">.. there is no result!!

please help me on how to call the $newfunc..

thank u!!

```
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function newreq () {
        var $newfunc = $('<div class="div effect" />');
        for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            $newfunc = $('<div class="div effect" />').text(i);
            $('body').append($newfunc);
        }enter code here
    });
</script>
    <title>Topics</title>

</head>
<body onload= "$newfunc();">

</body>
```

Comment: Actually `$(document).ready()` will be called automatically on body load event. You do not need to setup `$newfunc()`. I think you need to study jQuery/javascript basics a little more.

Comment: Can you post what the desired output would be? HTML as would be inspectd by using Chomes developer tools etc.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with your code?  In order to call a function called $newfunc() you need to define it as a function, not a jQuery object (and definitely not in $(document).ready()).  What you've posted is very confusing.

Let's stick to vanilla Javascript, since you are a little new.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newfunc() {
        var newdiv = '<div class="div effect" />';
        var body = document.getElementById("body");
        for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            body.innerHTML += newdiv;
        }
    }
</script>
<title>Topics</title>

</head>
<body id="body" onload="newfunc();">

</body>
```

Comment: I want to execute 6 div elements once the page is loaded.. i hve created css for div and want a jscript to execute the div.. and what other method I can use to call the function?